# finite $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f'(x)$. Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f'(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let f be twice differentiable function on R with finite $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f'(x)$. Then  $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f'(x) = 0$

I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: Thanks, Bill's solution is amazing in its simplicity!

Comment: Indeed. I love it.